# How to delete a set of lines from a file in Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a sample file like this.

```
[unit id="20"]
...blah blah...
[/unit]
[unit id="AB 560"]
...
[/unit]
[unit id="205"]
...
[/unit]
[unit id="AB 580"]
...
[/unit]
[unit id="120"]
...
[/unit]
[unit id="AB 210"]
...
[/unit]
```

I want to delete lines containing the string "AB" and 10 lines following it. To be specific, there will be 10 lines between `[unit ...]` and `[/unit]`. The output file should look like:

```
[unit id="20"]
...blah blah...
[/unit]
[unit id="205"]
...
[/unit]
[unit id="120"]
...
[/unit]
```

**Note**: Only "AB" will be present. No other character/string. I need an executable unix shell script for this -- no Perl, please.

Comment: This doesn't look like XML.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply find `AB`, and then delete both such line and the 10 lines following it. As pointed by @Lev Levitsky, this allowed by `GNU sed` only:

```
sed '/AB/,+10 {d}' <infile>
```

If you want to apply the modifications to the given file, just add the flag `-i`, for in-place substitution. Notice, as pointed by @Jens, that this is a `GNU`ism:

```
sed -i '/AB/,+10 {d}' <infile>
```

Comment: +1, it works for me (at least on GNU sed). Where did you learn that though? The best reference I know is [this one](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), and I didn't see it there. P.S. You don't need `{}` for a single command, btw.

Comment: @LevLevitsky haha I do sometimes wander throughout `man` pages, looking for novelties, and one of these days I reached the **Addresses** section of `man sed`. The `{}` I like to add, just to clarify things up, like while defining `sort` key-ranges: `sort -k 1n,1 ...`. Thanks for the tip, anyway! (:

Comment: `sed -i` for in-place edits is a GNUism and should be avoided in portable code. There is however talk about including it in a future POSIX revision (more than 5 years away, I'd say).

Comment: You're right, found it in `man sed`... Says it's the `GNU sed`-only trick as well.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I'm not very acquainted with `GNU-only` restraints -- more because I don't think I've ever used anything other than `GNU`. I'll look for an OS without `GNU` apps, in order to learn a bit about it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Me neither :) But people around here tend to nitpick about such stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

You may prefer to do it based on patterns and not just `+ 10lines`.

```
perl -n -e 'unless(/^\[unit.*AB.*\]/../\[\/unit\]/) { print; }'  tx
```

tx file is

```
[unit id="20"]
20...blah blah...
[/unit]
[unit id="AB 560"]
AB...
[/unit]
[unit id="205"]
205 ...
[/unit]
[unit id="AB 580"]
AB...
[/unit]
[unit id="120"]
120...
[/unit]
[unit id="AB 210"]
AB...
[/unit]
```

Gives

```
[unit id="20"]
20...blah blah...
[/unit]
[unit id="205"]
205 ...
[/unit]
[unit id="120"]
120...
[/unit]
```